# SVN link broken while renaming workspace

Tags: eclipse, svn

I had SVN project in my `w1`. I decide to rename `w1` to `w2` by Linux `mv` command. When I have opened `w2` from `eclipse` and found that project has no more `SVN` link. Then I renamed `w2` back to `w1` and opened with `Eclipse`. Still no `SVN` link. Where eclipse stores `SVN` info, why it breaks by renaming workspace and how to fix problem?

Answer (score 1):

try re-connecting your project(s) to repository by

```
right click on project > team > share project > (select repos) > next > use project settings
```

this is for subversive plugin, if your plugin is subclipse it may be little different (but same way)

this way you are re-connecting your project(s) to the repository with existing subversion metadata residing in project folder